# Git (BitBucket) Capistrano

Tags: git, capistrano, bitbucket, devops

Can someone help with this, I've setup Bitbucket & Capistrano and are testing deploying to remote servers but I can't get it to deploy to a root directory, I've looked around but can't seem to find a way to change it.

e.g. /var/www/html/web_app/

but i get this

e.g. /var/www/html/releases/20161028093829

Any ideas. Thanks in advance.

version "3.6.1"

deploy.rb

```
set :application, "hunter"
set :repo_url, "git@bitbucket.org:*****.git"
# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 2
```

CAPFILE

require "capistrano/setup"

require "capistrano/rsync"

require "capistrano/deploy"

require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }

Rake::Task[:production].invoke

Comment: Post some of your environment configuration so we can help you better. Which version of Capistrano are you using? Probably it is a misconfiguration of `:deploy_to` (http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/structure/)

Comment: Thanks  you alejdg.....See above

Comment: Did you have any success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter responsible for defining the directory to deploy to is `:deploy_to`. So, in order to your Capistrano to deploy to `/var/www/html/web_app/` you need to configure it accordingly.

Below `set :keep_releases, 2` set the `:deploy_to` param to `/var/www/html/web_app/`. Your *deploy.rb* file will look like this:

```
set :application, "hunter"
set :repo_url, "git@bitbucket.org:*****.git"
# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 2
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/html/web_app"
```